# Timestamp & Incremental Value in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, azure

I am new to SQL Queries . Currently I am looking as to why data is not being copied into the sink table .

Source query is :

```
**select * from Table_Name where
TimeStamp > '@{activity('OldValue').output.firstRow.IncrementValue}' and 
TimeStamp<= '@{activity('NewValue').output.firstRow.NewIncrementValue}**'
```

I am unable to find any information as to what does the where clause does.

Could anyone please let me know or point me to good article regarding this.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: would you understand it if it was written like: `where TimeStamp > '2000-01-01' and TimeStamp<= '2000-01-02'` ? Just trying to get an understanding of where you "don't get it"

Comment: What does these statement means : 
@{activity('OldValue').output.firstRow.IncrementValue
@{activity('NewValue').output.firstRow.NewIncrementValue}

Comment: Syntax highlighting shows your mistake - quote chars in `@{activity('OldValue').output.firstRow.IncrementValue}` interferes with ones in query text.

Comment: Hi @ag1, Kindly let me know if you need more information. : )

Comment: Hi @ag1. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. : )

Answer (score 1):

Do you add dynamic content to it? Your grammar is correct.

```sql
select * from Table_Name where
TimeStamp > '@{activity('OldValue').output.firstRow.IncrementValue}' and 
TimeStamp<= '@{activity('NewValue').output.firstRow.NewIncrementValue}'
```

I created a simple test:

1. Use Query and add dynamic content. Here I'm using:

```
select * from [dbo].[product] where CREATE_TIME> '@{activity('OldValue').output.firstRow.IncrementValue}' and CREATE_TIME<= '@{activity('NewValue').output.firstRow.NewIncrementValue}'
```

[image]
ADF will parse this expression to a string value:

2. Enter the above code, ADF will parse the expressions to string values.
   [image]

Comment: Great !! I am testing it .